# Canvas doesn't draw

Tags: java, android

I've set app view on XML based layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.mlayout);
```

with some views objects on it. Then, I added another view via:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game);
layout.addView(new GamePanel(this));
```

Where GamePanel class head looks like this:

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

I've created a view object programmatically in GamePanel class, and tried to set it's X to its pos.X + 1 on each update. From logcat, the X is really changing to X+1 on each update, but on mobile screen the object is still on the same place (it didn't moved nor a bit; it's still on the place where it was placed first during creating). Why it doesn't move?

Draw method in GamePanel:

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (canvas!=null)
        {
            final int savedState = canvas.save();

            if (objects != null)
            {
                for (Object o: objects)
                {
                    o.draw(canvas); 
                }
            } 
            canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a thread running that updates your surfaceview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am  not exactly sure what your problem is. Did you place the pos.X + 1 in the proper place. Could you edit to show the object? Then maybe your problem could be solved. For a start, you should check where you placed all your objects and everything. That is were the errors usually come.